# Google Firestore rules for a class blog

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I volunteered to make a class blog for my English class where everyone can make an account and post stuff. I used Google firebase for this, the Authentication and Firestore. Anyone can sign up and post their thing. Everything works fine except for the database security rules, right now, it's on **test mode** so anyone can do anything to the data.

The structure of it is:

/users/{Authentication UID}:
- joined
- name
- uid (this is a token generated from javascript used for the profile page and others)

/posts/{PID}:
- date
- pid
- post
- title
- uid

/comments/{PID}:
- comment
- date
- pid
- uid

To clear up some things: there are two uids, one as the document name which is from the Authentication and another which is a token generated from JavaScript used for the posts, comments and profile page.

All I ask for is one simple thing. **What rules should I use to secure the data?** I had a look at the firebase docs but ended up with no luck.

**EDIT 1:** Changed the accepted answer's rules a bit and got it working (I think):

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if true;
    }

    match /users/{userId} {
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
    match /posts/{postId} {
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
      allow update, delete: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.uid == resource.data.uid;
    }
    match /comments/{commentId} {
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
      allow update, delete: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.uid == resource.data.uid;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is unclear in the docs?  What have you tried that isn't working the way you'd expect?

Comment: It's up to you to translate your security requirements into rules.  Please make an attempt at doing this, and if what you're doing isn't working the way you expect, post a question with the rules and code.  Start with the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started

Comment: I used the docs again along with the accepted answer's rules to modify it a bit and make it work (I think), thanks for that! @DougStevenson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the following rules you can use for your firestore database

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
//create document id with users UID assigned by firestore, while creating a users document, this rules allows users to read and write only their data
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
//post id is random id generated by firebase
    match /posts/{postId} {
      //allows authenticated users to create or read posts
      allow read, create: if request.auth.uid != null;
      //allows users to update or delete only their posts.
      allow update, delete: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/posts/$(request.auth.uid)).data.uid == request.auth.uid;
    }
//comment id is random id generated by firebase
    match /comments/{commentId} {
      //allows authenticated users to create or read comments
      allow read, create: if request.auth.uid != null;
      //allows users to update or delete only their comments.
      allow update, delete: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/posts/$(request.auth.uid)).data.uid == request.auth.uid;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I went through the docs again before you posted this and I think I somewhat understand it. So I'm kind of confused with the update, delete rule for comments and posts because the name for those docs are a randomly generated token from javascript and not "request.auth.uid". It then gets the uid which is another randomly generated string from javascript and compares it to the auth uid. Like i've mentioned. there are 2 different uids for all users. But I have to really thank you for this as it has given me something to start with, I will try to modify this and let you know if it works!

Comment: I edited the question with the modified rules, it works (I think). Thanks again!

Comment: ok, glad that it worked, write rule is generalised rule for create, update and delete. so u can either use write or if u want more granular rules, u can use 3 rules

Comment: i have suggested a edit for your rules, for please check the edit